# Constructing a $3 \times 3$ Principal curvature tensor (sometimes just called a curvature tensor) in the global coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, coordinate-systems, surfaces, curvature

I have seen several sources ("Consistent Computation of First and Second-Order Differential Quantities for Surface Meshes" as an example) using the equation $$\mathbf{C}=\kappa_1\mathbf{\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^T}  + \kappa_2\mathbf{\hat{e}_2\hat{e}_2^T}$$ in a local coordinate system for the $(3\times3)$ principal curvature tensor $\mathbf{C}$ (I understand its not accurate to call it the curvature tensor, but that's what most people refer to it as). Here $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are the principal curvatures and $\mathbf{\hat{e}_1}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{e}_2}$ are the principal directions in the local coordinate system. We can then transform the "Curvature Tensor" to the global coordinate system using $$\mathbf{C_g}=\mathbf{QCQ^T}$$ (Here $\mathbf{Q}$ is an orthogonal column matrix comprised of the 3 coordinate axes of the local coordinate system in term of the global coordinate system. So essentially $2$ tangential vectors and $1$ normal vector to a given surface at a point, but all in terms of global coordinates). Could we instead construct the $3 \times 3$ principal curvature tensor directly from the principal directions, if we already had them in terms of the global coordinate system?
So I would use the same equation for $\mathbf{C_g}$ as for $\mathbf{C}$ but with principal directions $\mathbf{\hat{e}_1}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{e}_2}$ now in terms of the global coordinate system. That would essentially mean doing $$\mathbf{C_g}=\kappa_1\mathbf{Q\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^TQ^T}+\kappa_2\mathbf{Q\hat{e}_2\hat{e}_2^TQ^T}$$ where I would be performing the transformation on the tensors $\mathbf{\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^T}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{e}_2\hat{e}_2^T}$ instead of on $\mathbf{C}$. Of course I wouldn't actually be doing this transformation since I already have the principal directions in the global coordinate system. (I am not sure, but I guess this question is more about rules of tensor transformation than Differential Geometry)

Comment: Mathematicians do not call this the curvature tensor. So your "most people" pulls from a different audience. This is a matrix representation of the *shape operator* or *Weingarten map* — the derivative of the Gauss map of a surface in $\Bbb R^3$, I presume. The principal directions have nothing to do with a coordinate system, but they do have to do with a surface in $\Bbb R^3$. Your $Q$ matrix is actually an *orthogonal matrix* (so the columns form an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$). Yes, this is just a standard change of basis formula.

Comment: Hello Ted, thanks for your answer. You are right, I used the term "most people" rather loosely. I understand that Q is an orthogonal matrix that can be used as a change of basis matrix, which is why I wanted to use it directly on $\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^T$ and $\hat{e}_2\hat{e}_2^T$. I presume you are saying that I can do what I asked in my question? Also, aren't the principal directions tangent vectors in the direction of  principal curvatures and so could be represented in terms of any coordinate system, local or global?

Comment: Right. So you're actually doing a change of basis for a linear map (rather than a symmetric bilinear form), but since $Q$ is orthogonal, $Q^{-1}=Q^\top$. My only concern would be that perhaps $Q$ and $Q^\top=Q^{-1}$ should be reversed in your formula.

Comment: Thanks Ted, that's a really clear answer. I think I'll use this general equation to construct my matrix (and double-check the formula as you suggested). However, why would you call it a linear map, isn't the $\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^T$ matrix bilinear?